# taking the first non null in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get the first non null value from multiple pandas series in a dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
              'b':[np.nan, 5, np.nan, np.nan],
              'c':[np.nan, 55, 13, 14],
              'd':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4],
              'e':[12, np.nan, np.nan, 22],
          })

     a    b     c    d     e
0  2.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  12.0
1  NaN  5.0  55.0  NaN   NaN
2  NaN  NaN  13.0  NaN   NaN
3  NaN  NaN  14.0  4.0  22.0
```

in this `df` I want to create a new column `'f'`, and set it equal to `'a'` if a is not null, `'b'` if b is not null etc. down to e.

I could do a bunch of np.where statements which is inefficient.

```
df['f'] = np.where(df.a.notnull(), df.a,
              np.where(df.b.notnull(), df.b,
                   etc.))
```

I looked into doing `df.a or df.b or df.c` etc.

result should look like:

```
     a    b     c    d     e   f
0  2.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  12.0   2
1  NaN  5.0  55.0  NaN   NaN   5
2  NaN  NaN  13.0  NaN   NaN  13
3  NaN  NaN  14.0  4.0  22.0  14
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One solution

```
df.groupby(['f']*df.shape[1], axis=1).first()
Out[385]: 
      f
0   2.0
1   5.0
2  13.0
3  14.0
```

The orther

```
df.bfill(1)['a']
Out[388]: 
0     2.0
1     5.0
2    13.0
3    14.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Nice, but no need for a numpy array: `df.groupby(['f']*df.shape[1], axis=1).first()`; I also name `axis=1` because I don't know the order of the arguments of `groupby` by heart :)

Comment: df.bfill(1)['a'] seems to be the most efficient though!!

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `first_valid_index`

```
In [336]: df.apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1)
Out[336]:
0     2.0
1     5.0
2    13.0
3    14.0
dtype: float64
```

Or, `stack` and `groupby`

```
In [359]: df.stack().groupby(level=0).first()
Out[359]:
0     2.0
1     5.0
2    13.0
3    14.0
dtype: float64
```

Or, `first_valid_index` with lookup

```
In [355]: df.lookup(df.index, df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index, axis=1))
Out[355]: array([ 2.,  5., 13., 14.])
```

Comment: Note that `df.first_valid_index()` is to be used with `df.loc` (and not `df.iloc`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `numpy` for this:

```
first_valid = (~np.isnan(df.values)).argmax(1)
```

Then use indexing:

```
df.assign(valid=df.values[range(len(first_valid)), first_valid])
```

```
     a    b     c    d     e  valid
0  2.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  12.0    2.0
1  NaN  5.0  55.0  NaN   NaN    5.0
2  NaN  NaN  13.0  NaN   NaN   13.0
3  NaN  NaN  14.0  4.0  22.0   14.0
```